# How to handle mutiple streams in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stream, concatenation

I am writing a image manipulation service and I have to transform an image into multiple sizes

```
const writable1 = storage(name1).writableStream();
const writable2 = storage(name2).writableStream();
const writable3 = storage(name3).writableStream();

//piping the file stream to their respective storage stream
file.stream.pipe(imageTransformer).pipe(writable1);
file.stream.pipe(imageTransformer).pipe(writable2);
file.stream.pipe(imageTransformer).pipe(writable3);
```

I want to know when all the streams are finished writing to destination

Right now I have only checked for one stream like:

```
writable3.on('finish', callback);
//error handling
writable3.on('error', callback);
```

I have seen libraries like `https://github.com/mafintosh/pump` and `https://github.com/maxogden/mississippi` but these libraries only show writing to a single destination with multiple transforms.

How would I be able to check if all the streams are finished writing or one of them has errored out? How can I handle them in an array?

Comment: You need to promisify, this may be helpful https://www.npmjs.com/package/pipe-streams-to-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination converting stream to promise and `Promise.all`.

In the example, I have used [stream-to-promise](https://github.com/bendrucker/stream-to-promise) library for the stream to promise conversion.

For each stream, a promise is created. The promise is resolved when the stream is completed and rejected when the stream fails.

```
const streamToPromise = require('stream-to-promise')

const promise1 = streamToPromise(readable1.pipe(writable1));
const promise2 = streamToPromise(readable2.pipe(writable2));

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).
    .then(() => console.log('all the streams are finished'));
```